# My email based support form on my shared host is being blocked by Gmail

Tags: email, spam, shared-hosting, forms, gmail

On my site (developed with `ASP.NET`, if that matters) I have a support form, which is nothing more than three fields (i.e., name, email, and message) plus a Send button.

The form code generates emails from provided user input and sends them to: `support@mysite.com`. The form uses this address to send the messages:  `sender@mysite.com`. All the email for `mysite.com` is handled by Google Apps for Business.

The problem is: Google recently started marking emails sent from `sender@mysite.com` as spam:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     support@mysite.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain mysite.com by aspmx.l.google.com. [74.125.25.26].

The error that the other server returned was:
550-5.7.1 [ip-address-was-here       7] Our system has detected that this message is
550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail,
550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit
550-5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131 for
550 5.7.1 more information. sz7si15854448pab.203 - gsmtp
```

Obviously, visitors on my site **can** put spam messages in my support form. Anyway, I would prefer that these messages to end up in my Spam folder (or better the Inbox!) of `support@mysite.com`.

So, what can I do to prevent Google from blocking `sender@mysite.com`?

Shall I use a 3rd-party service for the support form? Or shall I tweak my site / form code somehow?

My site is on shared hosting if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [SMTP transaction](http://slett.net/spam-filtering-for-mx/smtpintro.html), the email servers for Gmail (used for Google Apps for Business) responded back that the IP address for your shared host's mail server is likely associated with unsolicited mail:

`[ip-address-was-here  7] Our system has detected that this message is likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, this message has been blocked.`

You can report this to your shared hosting provider and request that they either attempt to remove their IP address from Gmail's filter list and other [DNS Blacklists](http://slett.net/spam-filtering-for-mx/dnschecks.html) (not likely a quick fix), or switch you to a server with a different IP address that isn't listed in these or blocked by Gmail.

Alternatively, you can use a mail form provided by a third-party. Tweaking your form code however isn't going to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because the email is seen as mass email, and has no unsubscribe button or acknowledgement of where it comes from (company name etc).

Third-party emailers can help your emails to be trusted more often.